# Twig: Pass textfield value as routing parameter

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, routes, twig

I'm trying to route to another page and I need a textfield value to be passed along. This is my code:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    <button onclick="host()">Host the session</button>
    <button onclick="join()">Join as player</button>
    <label>
        Player name:
        <input type="text" id="nameField">
    </label>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        function host() {
            location.href = "{{ path('host') }}";
        }

        function join() {
            location.href = "{{ path('player', {'playerName' : nameField.value}) }}";
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I click on join, I get a Runtime Exception saying 'nameField' does not exist. I tried putting the textfield value into a javascript variable, but I can't reference that one either.
Is it possible to route like this at all? Alternatively, could I somehow avoid using javascript and route in the body block directly?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle, it will help you build the URL purely using JS

Comment: It seems weird to me that my very basic use case requires a community bundle. Is there no other way to reference a simple textfield inside Twig?

Comment: Your "very basic use case" is not supported by Symfony itself, as it is not based solely on backend generation of routes: when Twig runs, there is no such field as `nameField` to access the value from

Comment: That sounds like what I'm doing is not best practice for symfony. Would it be 'cleaner' to create a form containing my textfield inside a controller and then use the response to route?

Comment: The problem is, that twig renders the template before it is passed to the client where the JS is being processed. So on your server it tries to replace the attribute `nameField.value` that is intended for JS to already resolve which URL to use. Either you replace it with a valid placeholder-value that will be switched out using JS, use a static URL instead of the helper-method from twig or you could look into the bundle.

Comment: ^ this or get the route by using `ajax`

Answer (score -1):

You need to get it from app.request array.

This works for POST

```
app.request.get('nameFiled')
```

This works for GET

```
app.request.query.get('nameFiled')
```

if your input name is nameField

```
<input name="nameField">
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `OP`'s issue